# Error in : sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I am Using Linux Mint 17.

I try to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository/dists/apt-build/main/binary-i386/Packages File not found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get clean` and repeat your command

Comment: Nope @nssudo  not working !!

Comment: edit the contents of:

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build.list`

From:

`deb file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main`

to:

`deb [arch=amd64] file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main`

Comment: @nssad worked !!! thanks... Please post in answer !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit the contents of: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-build.list`

From: `deb file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main`

to: `deb [arch=amd64] file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository apt-build main`